# Swiper type error with ESLint and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js, react-swiper

I'm making a NextJS 12 Typescript swiper carousel. In developer mode, it runs fine, but when I run `npm run build`, it returns Type error

```
./src/layouts/components/ProductDetailContainer.tsx:56:17
Type error: Type '{ children: Element[]; navigation: boolean; modules: SwiperModule[]; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & SwiperProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'navigation' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & SwiperProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

  54 |       <Grid container spacing={4}>
  55 |         <Grid item xs={4}>
> 56 |         <Swiper navigation={true} modules={[Navigation]} className="mySwiper">
     |                 ^
```

Here is my versions:

- ```
  "swiper": "^10.2.0",
  ```
- ```
  "react": "17.0.2",
  ```
- ```
  "next": "^12.3.4",
  ```

I have followed this instruction from Swiper page but I could not make it work: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/2k3jk3?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: Have you solved this one? I'm getting the same exact issue.